# JavaScript regular Expression to extract a substring which is in double qoutes, from a master string

Tags: javascript, json, string

i have a string , which look like an array of strings. I need a regex pattern in javascript to extract the substrings inside that master string, and return me the substring. Look at the string given below, and i need a regex on the basis of this string. And the regex will extract the substrings like : 
files/file/img1.jpg ,files/file/img2.jpg and so on, until the end. As much directories i have , i want them to be extracted. For time being just consider that its not an array, its just a string. Thank you

```js
str =
 "["files/file/img1.jpg","files/file/img2.jpg","files/file/img3.jpg","files/file/img4.jpg","files/file/img5.jpg","files/file/img6.jpg"] ";
```

Comment: does [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) not work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse your string.Then just iterate over the array.

```js
var str =
 '["files/file/img1.jpg","files/file/img2.jpg","files/file/img3.jpg","files/file/img4.jpg","files/file/img5.jpg","files/file/img6.jpg"]';
 
var result = JSON.parse(str);
for(var i= 0; i< result.length;i++){
    console.log(result[i]);
}
```

Comment: @CodeTech this ansewer is same as my answer right? in this example he is looping. in my answer i just joined with , . to show you all the strings

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is kinda wrong. It should be:

```
var str ="[\"files/file/img1.jpg\",\"files/file/img2.jpg\",\"files/file/img3.jpg\",\"files/file/img4.jpg\",\"files/file/img5.jpg\",\"files/file/img6.jpg\"] ";
```

Apart from that we can just use multiple Javascript string manipulation functions to extract the string:

```
data = str.split('["')[1].split('"]')[0].replace(/"/g, "").split(',');
```

Now the variable data is an array which has all the directories you need. The output looks something like this:

```
 (6) ["files/file/img1.jpg", "files/file/img2.jpg", "files/file/img3.jpg", "files/file/img4.jpg", "files/file/img5.jpg", "files/file/img6.jpg"]
```

You can get each directory by indexing it: data[0] is the first one.